# Geofence Not triggered when but if use any map related application it is happens

Tags: android, geofencing, android-geofence

Geofence not triggered in my app but when opening any locations uses Applications it is working fine basically it is related on Android 13

I am using geofence Api and i am expecting when i am in geofence area my app is not open it is working properly at any conditions if internet is available in my app

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/218335535When I create a geofence and then go to a specific location (physically) - I never get a notification about it (tested on Android 11 devices: Google Pixel 2, OnePlus 7 Pro, Samsung Galaxy Tab A7 and emulators). The notification never happens. Waited for minutes, half-hour, hour.facing same problem